# Getting new line in select bootstrap using php

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

```
<select class="form-control" id="contract_package">
    <?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo '<option value="'. $row['contract_package'].'">'.$row['contract_package'].'<option>';  
     }
    ?>
</select>
```

The following piece of code gives me a new line two different options.
[image]

Please help me to remove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line

```
echo '<option value="'. $row['contract_package'].'">'.$row['contract_package'].'<option>';
```

To

```
echo '<option value="'. $row['contract_package'].'">'.$row['contract_package'].'</option>';
```

What I did is change second `<option>` to closing `</option>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

close your option tag

```
echo '<option value="'. $row['contract_package'].'">'.$row['contract_package'].'</option>';
```